# Setting a counter appropriately in sequentially rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I have two problems.

**Problem 1:**

I have a table of values with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Id int, Column1 int);
```

Let's assume the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers (Id int, Column1)
VALUES
 (1, 1),
 (2, 0),
 (3, 0),
 (4, 0),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 1),
 (7, 1),
 (8, 0),
 (9, 1),
 (10, 1),
 (11, 0),
 (12, 1);
```

What I want is a T-SQL query to generate the following data as desired output:

```
 Id, Column1, GroupID
 (1, 1, 1)
 (2, 0, 2)
 (3, 0, 3)
 (4, 0, 4)
 (5, 1, 5)
 (6, 1, 5)
 (7, 1, 5)
 (8, 0, 6)
 (9, 1, 7)
 (10, 1, 7)
 (11, 0, 8)
 (12, 1, 9)
```

Whenever sequential 1s exists the counter is repeated/copied.

**Problem 2:**

I have a table of values with schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (Id int, Column1 int, Column2 int);
```

Let's assume the following data:

```
INSERT INTO Numbers (Column1, Column2)
VALUES
 (1, 1, 1),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (3, 1, 0),
 (4, 1, 0),
 (5, 1, 1),
 (6, 1, 1),
 (7, 1, 1),
 (8, 1, 0),
 (9, 1, 1),
 (10, 1, 1),
 (11, 1, 0),
 (12, 1, 1),

 (13, 1),
 (14, 0),
 (15, 0),
 (16, 0),
 (17, 1),
 (18, 1),
 (19, 1),
 (20, 0),
 (21, 1),
 (22, 1),
 (23, 0),
 (24, 1);
```

What I want is a T-SQL query to generate the following data as desired output:

```
 Id, Column1, Column2, GroupID
 (1, 1, 1, 1)
 (2, 1, 0, 2)
 (3, 1, 0, 3)
 (4, 1, 0, 4)
 (5, 1, 1, 5)
 (6, 1, 1, 5)
 (7, 1, 1, 5)
 (8, 1, 0, 6)
 (9, 1, 1, 7)
 (10, 1, 1, 7)
 (11, 1, 0, 8)
 (12, 1, 1, 9)

 (13, 2, 1, 1)
 (14, 2, 0, 2)
 (15, 2, 0, 3)
 (16, 2, 0, 4)
 (17, 2, 1, 5)
 (18, 2, 1, 5)
 (19, 2, 1, 5)
 (20, 2, 0, 6)
 (21, 2, 1, 7)
 (22, 2, 1, 7)
 (23, 2, 0, 8)
 (24, 2, 1, 9)
```

Whenever sequential 1s exists the counter is repeated/copied. However, whenever a new value arrives for Column1 the counter is reset.

--

The T-SQL queries need to run in MS SQL Server in Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Comment: You. Can't. Unless there is another column that could be used to determine the order of data.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered rows.  You have no column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Just a side note, you should really try to avoid reserved words like COLUMN and VALUES

Comment: Unless your table gets an identity column or other explicit way of recording the insert order, there is no safe way to query the rows "in order". Queries that *appear* to work are readily written, but they *will* break down one day, as rows get shuffled around or the optimizer decides to introduce parallelism because your tables have gotten awfully big. As this is not a detail but a requirement for getting a solution at all, I recommend you modify your tables accordingly.

Comment: Hi @SalmanA I have added the identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's query works if the condition is changed to `or not (column1=1 and prev_column=1)` which is equivalent to `or column1!=1 or prev_column!=1`. This query :

```
select Id,Column1,
       sum(case when prev_column is null or column1!=1 or prev_column!=1
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (order by id) as GroupID
from (select t.*, lag(column1) over (order by id) as prev_column
      from @numbers t
     ) t;
```

Returns

```
Id  Column1 GroupID
1   1   1
2   0   2
3   0   3
4   0   4
5   1   5
6   1   5
7   1   5
8   0   6
9   1   7
10  1   7
11  0   8
12  1   9
```

The second problem works the same for each different `Column2` value. This calls for `PARTITION BY column2`:

```
 select Id,Column1,Column2,
       sum(case when prev_column is null or column2!=1 or prev_column!=1
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (partition by column1 order by id) as GroupID
from (select t.*, lag(column2) over (partition by column1 order by id) as prev_column
      from @numbers t
     ) t;
```

This produces:

```
Id  Column1 Column2 GroupID
1   1   1   1
2   1   0   2
3   1   0   3
4   1   0   4
5   1   1   5
6   1   1   5
7   1   1   5
8   1   0   6
9   1   1   7
10  1   1   7
11  1   0   8
12  1   1   9
13  2   1   1
14  2   0   2
15  2   0   3
16  2   0   4
17  2   1   5
18  2   1   5
19  2   1   5
20  2   0   6
21  2   1   7
22  2   1   7
23  2   0   8
24  2   1   9
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering.  One uses `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_column is null or prev_column <> column
                then 1 else 0
           end) over (order by ?)
from (select t.*, lag(column) over (order by ?) as prev_column
      from t
     ) t;
```

`?` is for the ordering column.

Comment: Hi Mr. Gordon Linoff I have re-edited the question, now I have two problems. The solution you provided me is for the problem 1?

Comment: I have tried your solution but it seems that the counter is copied/reused in sequential zeros too. I want only for sequential 1s this to happen. Check here the example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=264b9bfc18c0220013422d47c5cc8290

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis `Problem 2` is invisible. Post *one* question at a time, or make sure multiple questions are visible. In any case, as everyone has already explained, there's no order in a table unless you specify one with `ORDER BY` in a query. *Nothing* guarantees that the results will return in physical storage order.

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos I have made the question in bold, also I have added the Identity column.

Comment: The condition should be `or column1!=1 or prev_column!=1`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Where should I put this? Can you please fix it here and send me the url? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=537c1b124a309d91a6272a851190dac7

Comment: @EfstathiosChatzikyriakidis I posted an answer

Comment: `select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_column = 1 and prev_column = column1
            then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by ?)
from (select t.*, lag(column) over (order by ?) as prev_column
      from t
     ) t;`